# How to forward form values from one view to another using $request->all(); ? Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I pull all the values (topup amount and phone number) from a form on the index page and forward it to the checkout page:

```
public function topupPost(Request $request) {
        $validator = [
        'topupAmount'=> 'required|integer|between:1,100',
        'phonenumber'=> 'required|regex:/^05[602][0-9]{7}$/',
        ];

        $inputs = $request->all();

        Log::info($inputs);

        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $validator);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $validator->messages(),
                'code' => 400
            ], 400);
        }


        // return "Thanks! we'll take you to payment in a Giffy!";
        return view('pages.checkout', compact(inputs));
    }
```

How can I can I access the values of `inputs` which are: `phonenumber` and `topupAmount` in the checkout page template ?

I tried this:

```
<td>{{ app('inputs')->input('topupAmount') }} USD</td>
```

And it shows this error in the debugger :

> (1/1) ErrorException Use of undefined constant inputs - assumed
>   'inputs' in PagesController.php (line 39) at
>   HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Use of undefined constant inputs -
>   assumed \'inputs\'',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinerecharge\app\Http\Controllers\PagesController.php',
>   39, array('request' => object(Request), 'validator' =>
>   object(Validator), 'inputs' => array('_token' =>
>   'CsySUUecI0ekYNPY6oS1B2kleVHqNnrUKBpHbYwa', 'phonenumber' =>
>   '0501234567', 'topupAmount' => '1'))) in PagesController.php (line 39)

Comment: return view('pages.checkout', compact(inputs)); change to return view('pages.checkout', compact('inputs')); you forget to add ' ' this in your compact

Comment: and then in your view call like {{$input->phonenumber}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the values inside your pages/checkout.blade.php as follows:

```
{{ $inputs['phonenumber'] }}
```